# Join two tables using IN clause in spring data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have following two JPA entities

```
public class User {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private String id; 
  
  private String userName;
  
  private String courseStatus;
}

public class Course {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "course_id")
      private String id; 

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "user_id"))
      private User user;
     
      private String userStatus

}
```

I have a list of userNames (without ids). I need to join the user table with the course table based on an IN clause passing  and check that both userStatus and CourseStatus is "VALID". Is there a way to do this in a single query inside spring data JPA

Comment: Do you need course List ? or user list ?

Comment: We need user list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

In your `CourseRepository`

```java
@Query("select c.user from Course c where c.user.userName in(:userNames) and c.user.courseStatus ='VALID' and c.userStatus='VALID'")
List<User> findAllValidUsers(@Param("userNames") List<String> userNames)
```